# Trouble with replacement rules for squared variables

Tags: pattern-matching, semantic-matching

I want to do replacement of products (because I am dealing with abstract projectors), but Mathematica seems to fail understanding this toy example replacement :

```
x y y /. {x y -> 1}
```

> x y^2

because it doesn't understand that there is $xy$ in $xy^2$. Is there an easy way to deal with this kind of issues ?

Thanks!

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantic-matching

Comment: This helps, thanks. But for systematicity I would like to know if it is possible to forbid mathematica to replace $x x \to x^2$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood your question. Do you mean you want to stop the automatic evaluation of `x x`? If so, consider something like `Inactivate[x  x, Times]`, or even consider make your own (I admit it's a bit advanced): `SetAttributes[times, {Orderless, Flat, OneIdentity}];
expr = times[x, times[y, x]];
expr /. times[x, y] -> aaa`

Comment: Thanks! This is useful

Comment: Do you require something like `Hold[x y y] /. x y -> 1 // ReleaseHold` (giving `y` as output)?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
rep = {_[a_, _[b_, n_]] :> Times @@ Table[b, n - 1], Times[__] :> 1};

ReplaceAll[rep] /@ {x y, x y y, x y y y}
```

{1, y, y^2}

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `Simplify` with side relation

```
e = x  y  y
Simplify[e, {x*y == 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]